# Why doesn't java execute if-else statement correctly in Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create possibility for my web app to like any article by pressing like button. So this is how it works: you like something, so likes++ and if you like again, it deletes your previous like, like on Youtube, you can't get an infinite amount of them. But it doesn't work correctly. When I'm already in an array who liked this article, it writes me again, and counter updates. But I check every user with users who are in array. What's wrong? Thank you

```
public void likeProject(User user)
{
    if(users_liked.size() == 0) // If the are no users who liked this article, write this user
    {
        users_liked.add(user);
        setLikes(getLikes() + 1);
    }

    else // This is for array, which already has users who pressed like button
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < users_liked.size(); i++)
        {
            if(!user.getId().equals(users_liked.get(i).getId())) // i liked it before, so my object is in an array, so this shouldn't be executed
            {
                users_liked.add(user); // Idk why, but this it's executes every time i press the like button. I'm already in an array
                setLikes(getLikes() + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the type returned by your user.getId() ?

Comment: what does the user.getId() return and what does the array of user_liked getId's contain?

Comment: @Janar id is a string, this array contains java class called User, which has getter and setters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EI CHO already pointed out where the problem is. In my answer I want to propose a code correction; you could do something like that:

```cpp
// ...
else {
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < users_liked.size(); i++) {
        if(!user.getId().equals(users_liked.get(i).getId())) {
            continue;
        } else {
            // user found! unlike and process etc. etc.
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i == users_liked.size()) {
        // After traversing the array we didn't find the specified user
        // Add user to list and process likes
        users_liked.add(user);
        setLikes(getLikes() + 1);
    }
}
// ... etc. etc.
```

Cheers!

**EDIT**

To enhance my answer and your access time: As you can see, if you use an array as data structure to store User objects you will always have to traverse the full array to make sure that the User object you're looking for is not in the array. Thus, you always have to iterate n-times, i.e. your access time is O(n) (with n records)

To enhance your access time use a hash map (HashMap<String, User>) and the method #containsKey(Object key):boolean instead. Regardless of whether you have 10 or two million records, your access time remains constant O(1) – provided that your String identifier stays unique.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer: your condition was wrong.**

```
if(!user.getId().equals(users_liked.get(i).getId()))
```

If there were ten users in the user like list. And for the user you check, It will be checked at least ten times by the condition above.And each time it will get a true and add the user the to list for 10 times.

```
Input user: 11
(Before)User Like List: 
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Check 1 != 11, add 11 to the list.
Check 2 != 11, add 11 to the list.
...
Check 10 != 11, add 11 to the list.
Check 11 != 11, pass.
Check 11 != 11, pass.
...
Check 11 != 11, pass.

(After)User Like List:
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11]
```

Comment: All you need to do is 1. check if the user has already in the user like list. 2. if true, do the unlike logic. 3. if false, do the like logic(add user to the like list. etc.)